# extract URLs from href inside unordered lists and insert into mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, url

I have several unordered lists. The list items are URLs. How can I extract the URL and link text from each list item to insert into a database?

```
<ul id="1">
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="2">
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="3">
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="someplace.com">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know RegEx should be avoided. I already have the PDO set up. The ul id number goes into the categoryID on the mysql table.

The only thing that seems to make sense would be something like a while-loop with another loop inside to get the URLs and text, and then after increment the id. I just don't know how to start it. Should the URL and text go into an array?

Comment: Are you trying to insert them after the page is loaded and also is this dynamic content?

Comment: Why should regex be avoided?

Comment: I'm suspecting you will want to make use of `DOMDocument` or another PHP DOM library.

Comment: Nah. I only need to have this run once, just to get the existing lists I have inserted.

Comment: I think what is being asked is if you have these lists before you've sent them to the browser, or if you are trying to get them after they have been sent to the browser.

Comment: After they've been sent

Comment: what about `jquery` to get data and after store the data in database by `ajax` call

Comment: I might just use jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: If it's already been sent to the browser, then you should use jQuery to get the HTML, and send it back to the server via AJAX as XML data. Then you can use `DOMDocument` class in PHP or `simplexml` with XPath to easily extract the information in an intuitive way.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your HTML is stored in the string `$content`, you could use [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to extract the various list items without having to resort to regex.

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($content);
$lists = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');
foreach($lists as $list) {
  $id = $list->getAttribute('id');
  $links = $list->getElementsByTagName('a');
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $text = $link->nodeValue;
    // insert $id, $text and $href into the data here 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex just fine:

```
preg_match_all('/<a href=\"(.*?)\"[.*]?>(.*?)<\/a>/i', $string, $matches);

$insert = array();

foreach($matches as $val)
{
    /* DONT FORGET TO ESCAPE YOUR DATA IF NEEDED */
    $url = $val[0];
    $name = $val[1];

    $insert[] = 'INSERT INTO tableName (url, name) VALUES ("' . $url . '", "' . $name . '")';
}

print_r($insert);
```

Comment: Only problem with regex is it becomes hard to pick and choose which URLs you are capturing in a huge block. What if there are urls spread between the `<UL>` tags? Using the DOM gives the ability to apply some better filtering logic and readability at, perhaps, the cost of some speed.

Comment: The above regex only grabs the URLS from within the `href` attribute within `<a>` tags. It can quite easily be modified to look for `<a>` tags within `<li>` tags as well, I guess its preference.

Comment: The question as to why there is hesitancy in using regex was never answered. It's completely useful and viable for long-term support. Besides, if this is a one-off use, using something like Perl would be a better solution because if it's inherent wide support of regex features.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try `SimpleHTMLDom`, it's a PHP library i use for processing xml like documents.

You could easily go like so:

```
require_once("/path/to/simplehtmldom/library");
$parsed_data = array();
//we next need to create a dom object --
//case 1: let me assume the HTML is in a string
$dom_object = str_get_html($html_string);
//case 2: it's at a particular url
$dom_object = file_get_html("http://www.site-with-the-content.com");
//now we have our object
$links = $dom_object->find("ul li a");
//finds all the <a> tags on the page inside <ul>, you could filter it 
//using class or ids like with jQuery if you like
foreach($links as $link){
    $parsed_data[] = array(
        "link"=>$link->href,
        "text"=>$link->innertext
    );
}
//You can now go through your array of parsed content and insert into your DB
```

Hope this help :)

[SimpleHTMLDom Sourceforge project](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 0):

here is the `jQuery` version to extract your desired values
if you are trying to get them after they have been sent to the browser

```
var data=$("ul");
var values=new Array();
$.each(data,function(i){
values[i]=$(this).attr("id");
$.each($(this).find("li"),function(j){
values[i+"-"+j+"link"]=$(this).find("a").attr("href")
values[i+"-"+j+"text"]=$(this).find("a").text();
});
});
console.log(values)
```

Now send this array to your php file via `ajax` call

Hope it makes sense